# Repository Pattern, Unit of Work with Generics

Tags: c#

I have the following code (I have ommited certain areas to make it simple)

```
public interface ICustomer
{

    int Age { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : ICustomer
{

    public int Age { get; set; }


    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface ICustomerRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetCustomers();

    T GetCustomer();

    void AddCustomer(T customer);
}

public class CustomerRepository<T> : ICustomerRepository<T> where T:class 
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetCustomers()
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }


    public T GetCustomer()
    {
        return null;
    }


    public void AddCustomer(T customer)
    {

    }
}


public class UnitOfWork //: IUnitOfWork
{

    public ICustomerRepository<ICustomer> CusRepo
    {
        get
        {
            return new CustomerRepository<Customer>();
            //Error: Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert   type 'ConsoleApplication1.CustomerRepository<ConsoleApplication1.Customer>' to 'ConsoleApplication1.ICustomerRepository<ConsoleApplication1.ICustomer>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    
        }

    }
}
```

I get the following error in the UnitOfWork class.  How do I fix this?

.Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApplication1.CustomerRepository' to 'ConsoleApplication1.ICustomerRepository'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I cannot use covariance since the  parameter is used for both in and out purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You should return repository as following:

```
get
{
    return new CustomerRepository<ICustomer>();
}
```

You cannot use variance here because your `ICustomerRepository<T>` have generic parameter in both in and out positions. To use variance, you can split `ICustomerRepository<T>` into two separate interfaces, like these:

```
interface IReadRepository<out T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetItems();
    T GetItem(int id);
}

interface IWriteRepository<in T>
{
    void AddItem(T item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored the pattern in your sample code.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    int Save();
}

public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity, TKey> : IUnitOfWork where TEntity : class
{
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    TEntity Find(TKey id);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
}



public interface ICustomerRepository :IBaseRepository<Customer, int>
{

}

public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    public void Add(Customer entity)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Customer Find(int id)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Save()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private ICustomerRepository _customers;

    public ICustomerRepository Customers
    {
        get { return _customers; }
    }

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _customers = new CustomerRepository();
    }

    public int Save()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it helps to a certain extent.  I have a small issue in your solution.  My interfaces are in a separate project and my concrete implementations are in a separate project.  So I cannot do the following public interface (Customer is in a different project)     ICustomerRepository :IBaseRepository<Customer, int>